# My app crash with UTF8String in my request on ios7 but not on ios5

Tags: ios, objective-c

UPDATE WITH SOLUTION:

The problem was, the server was dc, and then i couldnt connect to it. Thanks to @Hot Licks i seen the error in the log, so thanks for all.

---

UPDATE: I tryed the Hot Licks code and then i get this log:

2014-03-04 `16:00:16.445 finalAbogados[3166:70b] Error from sendSynchronousRequest: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo=0x8c82840 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=localhost/scripts/logueoFinal.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=localhost/scripts/logueoFinal.php, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSUnderlyingError=0x8ac9480 "Could not connect to the server."} –`

I dont know how, but on iOS5 i can realize the connection, and now on iOS7 i cant. The code is the same. 
Could be that i have to use NSURLSession instead NSURLConnection?

Please help.

---

i updated my xcode to 5,0 with ios7, and now my app doesnt work.

The code send a request with POST method and then receive data from a server. If the data is correct go to the other view controller else show an alert.

This same code worked on ios5, but now after the update the app crash:

```
-(IBAction)logClicked:(id)sender {
    if ([user.text isEqualToString:@""] && [pass.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] initWithTitle:@"Alerta." message:@"Escriba un usuario y contraseña." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Volver" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else {

        NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@&pass=%@", user.text, pass.text];
        NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/scripts/logueoFinal.php"]];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];

        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;

        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];

        if ([content isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] initWithTitle:@"Bienvenido." message:@"El usuario y contraseña es correcto." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ingresar" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];


            asuntosViewController = [[AsuntosViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AsuntosViewController" bundle:nil];


            asuntosViewController.ureceived = user.text;
            asuntosViewController.preceived = pass.text;

            [self.view addSubview:asuntosViewController.view];

        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] initWithTitle:@"Error." message:@"El usuario y contraseña no es correcto." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Volver" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }

}
```

This is the log when the app is crashing:

```
2014-03-04 13:09:46.535 toiOS7[2707:70b] Could not load the "17905.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.microarea.toiOS7"
2014-03-04 13:09:59.995 toiOS7[2707:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173b5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014be8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0173b3bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   Foundation                          0x010d7662 +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:] + 90
    4   toiOS7                              0x00002d2e -[ViewController logClicked:] + 1342
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d0874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x0022e0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    7   UIKit                               0x0022e04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    8   UIKit                               0x003260c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x00326484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    10  UIKit                               0x00325733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    11  UIKit                               0x0026b51d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    12  UIKit                               0x0026c184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    13  UIKit                               0x0023fe86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    14  UIKit                               0x0022a18f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x016c483f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x016c41cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x016e129e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x016e0ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x016e08db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x036e09e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x036e0809 GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x0022cd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    23  toiOS7                              0x00003add main + 141
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d79701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I dont understand nothing, i was working so much time on my app and now doesnt work, please help.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: There are tons of pages related to your error. Google it.

Comment: Did you log `returnData`?

Comment: Im new on ios and i dont know what i have to search in google cause the log put a lot of errors. Can u send me a link with the solution? thanks

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi now i logged the returnData variable and is NULL. Why???? on iOS5 always content a value. Can u help me please? Am i doing something wrong with the request?

Comment: So, what does `error` say when you log it (as you should, since you got a nil value back from `sendSynchronousRequest`)??????  (The `error` parm is not there just to occupy space!)

Comment: @HotLicks i tryed ur code, the log prints: 2014-03-04 16:00:16.445 finalAbogados[3166:70b] Error from sendSynchronousRequest: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo=0x8c82840 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost/scripts/logueoFinal.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost/scripts/logueoFinal.php, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSUnderlyingError=0x8ac9480 "Could not connect to the server."}
------------------ I dont understand why, on iOS5 can connect to my server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out an important step:

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSString* content = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (returnData) {
    content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
} 
else {
    NSLog(@"Error from sendSynchronousRequest: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: i tryed your code, the log prints: 2014-03-04 16:00:16.445 finalAbogados[3166:70b] Error from sendSynchronousRequest: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo=0x8c82840 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost/scripts/logueoFinal.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost/scripts/logueoFinal.php, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSUnderlyingError=0x8ac9480 "Could not connect to the server."}